# How to access GMail APIs using api key or username password?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I am following [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go) instructions. I am wondering is there a way to authenticate the GMail APIs without Oauth, like API key or username/password. Using OAUth involves manual intervention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GMail api contains private user data.   In order to access private user data you must have their permission to access it.

You can access the Gmail api using Oauth2 to request permission of the user of the account to access their data.   If this is a gsuite account then you can set up [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation) to a service account and access it that way.

If its not a gsuite account you can have the user authenticate your application once and then store the refresh token using that to gain a new access token as needed but you will always need the users to authenticate your application at least once to get the refresh token.

Login and password is called client login and was turned off by google in 2015.  You can also go directly though the smtp or Imap servers using the users login and pass word.

Comment: Why isn't Google allowing users to make their own decisions about who to trust?

Comment: I can't answer that question, TBH I think they are

Comment: Curious what you mean by they are? You're getting me excited that they're planning to remove this restriction, lol. But I suspect you meant something else.

Comment: This restriction is in place to protect users so in that sense they are allowing developers to choose to use the system or not it's your choice.   If you want access to private user data Run through the oauth2 procces and get access.   I don't want you accessing my email without my permission

Comment: Oh I see. Well yes, of course you don't want me accessing your email without permission. No matter what, you have to grant permission though. I'm saying that by requiring developers to pay $10-$75k just to have the chance to ask for your permission filters out many potentially powerful new integrations, restricting what tools users can choose to trust.

Comment: Well about 10 years ago some bad actors abused the system that we had before that did not require verification.   and now **we** must pay the consequences.

Answer (score 0):

The link in DalmTo's answer above is now outdated. I am also setting this up for a Google Workspace (formally GSuite) account, and here is the updated link to Domain-wide delegation with a Service Account: https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#service-account